# How to send ajax data to rails 3. jQuery is escaping the string

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, json

I'm trying to do this:

```
$.ajax({
   type: "PUT",
   url: /example,
   data: {_method: "put", "foo_model[bar_attribute]": value_var }
});
```

And works as expected but I need to construct the part `foo_model[bar_attribute]`dynamically.

I'm trying with:

```
var model = "foo_model";
var attribute = "foo_attribute";
var param = model + "[" + attribute + "]";
var dataStr = '{_method: "put",' + param + ': ' + value + '}';
```

and again:

```
$.ajax({
   type: "PUT",
   url: /example,
   data: dataStr
});
```

But it doesn't work, jQuery is escaping quotes and adding curly brackets everywhere around...

Is there any better way to do this? I also tried other ways like making a json object, setting processData to false, as I saw in another post but nothing seems to be working... The request is always transformed and escaped. Also tried `unescape` but it only works if I write literally:

`data: {_method: "put", "foo_model[bar_attribute]": value_var }`

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use something like this (tested and working)

```
var model = "foo_model";
var attribute = "foo_attribute";
var param = model + "[" + attribute + "]";
var value = "test";

$.ajax({
  url: "http://fiddle.jshell.net/pu6ME/show/",
  type: "GET",
  data: param + '=' + value
}).done(function() {
   alert("Works!");
});
```

By using the `param + '=' + value` workaround you can actually use a dynamic name!
I believe it is not possible by using normal key : value syntax, but it doesn't matter in this example.

No need to define datastring.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/edwardmp/EwL9K/) example (use Control/Cmd + I to view network activity, and you'll see it works)